# objective-C loop a matrix world

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to use label to create a 15 * 15 matrix world.How to loop the row and column?

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 15, 15)];
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you need to create 50 Label of size 18x98

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i  = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (20 * x > self.view.frame.size.width) {
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }

        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20 * x, 100 * y, 18, 98)];
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
        x++;
    }
```